# Custom theme being prompted for update because of similarly named theme

Tags: themes

I've got a custom made theme named "Discovery 2014" on my site and it keeps getting flagged for an update because of a free theme named "Discovery" available via the theme repository. Definitely not my theme, of course. Is there anyway to disable this? I was thinking I might just crank up the version number to like 30 or something that the public theme will never reach. But is there a better or more proper way?

I could always re-name the theme (and going forward I will be using more uniquely identifiable names for themes), but then I'll have to set a ton of stuff back up again, won't I?

Comment: why not just delete the free theme?

Comment: It's not my theme to delete. Someone's free theme is similar enough in name to my custom theme that mine gets updates for theirs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no intended way whatsoever in WordPress to opt out of updates. Even *not* intended way is significantly convoluted and needs to intercept HTTP requests being made.

You can disable updates completely with `DISALLOW_FILE_MODS` constant.

If you have to retain update functionality for other stuff you will have to code it from scratch or use a third party implementation, such as [Update Blocker](https://github.com/Rarst/update-blocker) (disclosure — was created by me).

Comment: I was worried about that! I think I'll just up the version numbering on my theme and all it a day.